# Java Generic Context Type of super Class

Tags: java

The compliation of the CORE of [fluent-builders-generator](https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/) project
failed with the compilation error

The method endParameter() is undefined for the type JavaSourceBuilderBase.MethodParameterBuilderBase

[image]

The target line is

```
.withParameter().withType(..).withName("aInstance").endParameter()
```

the withParameter() return a Class witch effectivly contains the endParameter() but not his super Class

```
public class ParameterMethodParameterBuilder extends MethodParameterBuilderBase<ParameterMethodParameterBuilder> {
    public ParameterMethodParameterBuilder(com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.MethodParameter aInstance) {
         super(aInstance);
    }

    public GeneratorT endParameter() {
         return (GeneratorT) MethodBuilderBase.this;
    }
}
```

Now the super Class

```
public static class MethodParameterBuilderBase<GeneratorT extends MethodParameterBuilderBase> {
        private final com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.MethodParameter instance;

        protected MethodParameterBuilderBase(com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.MethodParameter aInstance) {
            instance = aInstance;
        }

        protected com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.MethodParameter getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        public GeneratorT withType(java.lang.String aValue) {
            instance.setType(aValue);

            return (GeneratorT) this;
        }

        public GeneratorT withName(java.lang.String aValue) {
            instance.setName(aValue);

            return (GeneratorT) this;
        }
    }
```

So the problem is that the withName() and withType() return the super Class that didn't contains the endParameter.

i think that this had a relation ship with compiler version or parameters.

About the context of GeneratorT

```
public class JavaSourceBuilder extends JavaSourceBuilderBase<JavaSourceBuilder> {
    public static JavaSourceBuilder javaSource() {
        return new JavaSourceBuilder();
    }

    public JavaSourceBuilder() {
        super(new com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.JavaSource());
    }

    public com.sabre.buildergenerator.sourcegenerator.java.JavaSource build() {
        return getInstance();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
class JavaSourceBuilderBase<GeneratorT extends JavaSourceBuilderBase> {
...
```

}

The complete class source code :  [JavaSourceBuilder.java](http://fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin.googlecode.com/hg-history/f7a812958be5e71adc5bbb918e49ef1a8e079481/plugin/src/com/sabre/buildergenerator/sourcegenerator/java/JavaSourceBuilder.java)

Comment: What is `GeneratorT` in the context of `ParameterMethodParameterBuilder`?

Comment: Do you think that might be your problem then?

Comment: It *appears* you're attempting to use the "curiously recurring template pattern" ... but kinda off a bit. That said, your subclass doesn't *have* a `GeneratorT` ... that's the generic type parameter of the base class that you're specifying when you extend it. Return a `ParameterMethodParameterBuilder`

Comment: Its not my code, its an open source project, i just want to build it

Answer (score 1):

I also had a look at the [fluent-builders-generator](https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/) but came to the same result. The generator part of the library is unfinished in sense that it won't compile. And even if you fix the `JavaSourceBuilder` problem using @Nassim MOUALEK's answer, you will fail later because the basic `ReflectionUtil`and `SignatureUtil` methods throw `UnsupportedException`. They are not implemented.

Anyways, this generator would have never worked. That's because you need the Builder on compile time, but the generator itself needs the compiled sources for introspection. If you are thinking about the maven build phases, this generator would be located at the `generate-sources` phase, in which the source code is not yet compiled. But the whole generator can only operate on already compiled classes.

Since the builders builder is an eclipse plugin, and is operating on source level, this concept works nicely with eclipse. That's most probably why the generator is unfinished.

If you are looking for a builder generator that actually works hava a look at [pojobuilder](https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder). It uses the `javax.annotation.processing.Processor` to generate the builders on compile time.

Answer (score 0):

After some manipulations, its looks that the project is not finished yet, but i succeed to run it whith some changes like:

```
p s class MethodParameterBuilderBase<GeneratorT extends MethodParameterBuilderBase> {
...
}
```

to

```
p s class MethodParameterBuilderBase<GeneratorT extends ParameterMethodParameterBuilder> {
....
}
```

this remove the compile exception