# Java Syntax expression.new MyClass

Tags: java

Having this function

```
public ParameterMethodParameterBuilder withParameter() {
        MethodParameter parameter = new MethodParameter();

  return withParameter(parameter).new ParameterMethodParameterBuilder(parameter);
}
```

What is the mean of the experession below

```
withParameter(parameter).new ParameterMethodParameterBuilder(parameter)
```

Comment: post `withParameter(MethodParameter parameter)` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `obj.new Inner()` creates and returns an instance of the inner class(*) `Inner` that is linked to the instance `obj` of the encapsulating class.

When an inner class is declared, you need an instance of the encapsulating class to instantiate the inner class. The syntax you are confronted to is exactly for this purpose.

Here is the simplest example for this:

```
public class MainClass {
    public class InnerClass {
    }
}
```

You would instantiate `InnerClass` this way:

```
MainClass mc = new MainClass();
mc.new InnerClass();
```

(*) inner class = **non-static nested** class

Comment: could you please help me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205527/java-generic-context-type-of-super-class

Answer (score 2):

`ParameterMethodParameterBuilder` is an inner class of whatever returning type of `withParameter(MethodParameter parameter)` method.

You care creating a new object of that inner class `ParameterMethodParameterBuilder` which having outer reference returned by `withParameter(parameter)` method

Comment: could you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205527/java-generic-context-type-of-super-class

Answer (score 0):

It creates a new instance of a nested class:

```
public class MethodParameter() {

    public class ParameterMethodParameterBuilder(/* ... */) {

        //...

    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Looking again at the original post, what makes you think the class `ParameterMethodParameterBuilder` is declared `static`? I suppose exactly that it isn't.

Comment: The inner class is very unlikely to be `static`.

Comment: Small mistake on my part, it definitely wouldn't be static. Just commonly how I declare my nested classes :)

Answer (score 0):

`withParameter(parameter)`  method returns MethodParameter instance and you are trying to create

object of ParameterMethodParameterBuilder static inner class,

so syntax goes like this
`MethodParameter.new ParameterMethodParameterBuilder (parameter)` to create your inner static class object

let me know for any issues.